# Go back to native app after launch of react native in existing project

Tags: ios, react-native, react-native-ios

I have successfully [integrated react native in existing project](https://facebook.github.io/react-native/docs/integration-with-existing-apps.html). In my native app I have a screen with a button that launch `react-native` screen.

In `Android` I can go back to previous screen with help of `BackAndroid.exitApp()`. How can I achieve same functionality in iOS?

Comment: iOS apps aren't supposed to close on their own unless the user closes them. Closing a app manually might get your app rejected from app store.

Comment: If you look at following tutorial [Integration With Existing Apps](https://facebook.github.io/react-native/docs/integration-with-existing-apps.html). First screen has two buttons, Play Game button (1st button) will launch `react-native` screen and there is no way to go back to your first screen after sucessfully launch of `react-native`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When I do flow integrations between native and RN I simply add a hook back in my native app and call that from RN. So in your example I would do something like

```
onBackButtonPress() {
  if (Platform.OS === 'ios') {
    NativeModules.SomeController.backPressed()
  }
  else {
    BackAndroid.exitApp()
  }
}
```

and then define `backPressed()` in your controller so logic can be placed there

```
RCT_EXPORT_METHOD(backPressed) {
    // logic to go back e.g. pop view controller or dismiss modal
}
```

Comment: Thanks, I am going to try this.

Comment: Does this mean, you are creating a custom ViewController ? whereas the facebook doc uses UIViewController.

Answer (score 0):

This can be done by dismissing top presented view controller of your app. In order to get the top view controller in your RCTBridge implementation you can use this code.

```
- (UIViewController *)currentTopViewController
{
    UIViewController *topVC = [[[[UIApplication sharedApplication] delegate] window] rootViewController];
    while (topVC.presentedViewController)
    {
        topVC = topVC.presentedViewController;
    }
    if ([topVC isKindOfClass:[UINavigationController class]]) {
        return [(UINavigationController *)topVC topViewController];
    }
    return topVC;
}
```

Then you can dismiss this view controller

```
[topViewController dismissViewControllerAnimated:YES completion:nil];
```

I developed a small npm package for achieving this. [Find it here](https://github.com/zsajjad/react-native-exit)